# Jmeter results average shows more time than AWS metrics

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter results average/min/max time shows more time than the service/server average/min/max actual results (AWS Lambda end point).

We have AWS Lambda end point which needs to be tested for Load testing, used Jmeter in distributed environment (1 Master, 2 slave EC2 instnaces).

Jmx file: one http request with ramp up of 1 second for 100 users. (no listeners, assertions added)

1. Jmeter version: 3.1
2. Running in Non-gui mode (Dockerized)
   Tested for 100 users (Jmeter results):
   Avg: 1.5 secs
   Max: 2 secs

AWS metrics:
Max: 200 milli seconds

Tried multiple times for the same scenario  however unable to get similar results at both the places.

Please guide what could be gone wrong or the way needs to be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My expectation is that AWS metrics show only server processing time while JMeter counts everything, to wit:

- Connect Time
- Latency (time to first byte)
- Overall response time (time to last byte)

So JMeter measures the time from when the request has just been sent until last byte of response received and AWS reports only time server spent processing the request, time for request to reach the server and response to reach JMeter is not included.

More information:

- [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [Time to first byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_byte)
- [How to Analyze the Results of a Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0)
- [Why You Should Be Measuring Time to Last Byte in 2018](http://blog.catchpoint.com/2017/12/07/measuring-time-last-byte-2018/)